# How do I uninstall Rust on Windows?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Before I begin, I have tried everything to uninstall rust, but nothing works. I installed it via [rust-lang.org](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install), but my computer simply does not recognize that rust exists in the first place. Whenever I try to run the installer, it says that everything is downloaded properly. [the directory is located somewhere that does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGcMy.png).

Whenever I try to uninstall rust, it simply does not recognize that rust is installed [It does not recognize rust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHk4o.png). I have tried restarting my computer multiple times and running the installer multiple times. I also downloaded the Microsoft visual studio dependencies.

Comment: The start menu isn't a good file explorer. Look for the directory in File Explorer.

Comment: It's still not there, I just checked and it does not exist

Comment: Depends on how you _installed_ rust in the first place. Question needs to specify that to be answerable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that share code as images instead of code blocks usually indicate you haven't read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and people often skip right over them. So share your code as indicated. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @DonBranson I do not have any code, because I have not figured out how to even write hello world. I have tried multiple times to create a rust file, but none worked. I have struggled with the installation of rust for over a week now and I just want to uninstall it so I can maybe reinstall it as a last ditch effort. I have read the How to Ask page and done the tour, but my knowledge of rust is so limited that I don't know how to specify my current problem further.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Moon0Jelly understood, but pull the text out of those images and share that instead of images. You'll be more likely to get good responses, and people with similar problems in the future are more likely to find the question and its answers.

Answer (score -2):

> View hidden files and folders in Windows
> Open File Explorer from the taskbar.
> Select View > Options > Change folder and search options.
> Select the View tab and, in Advanced settings, select Show hidden
> files, folders, and drives and OK.

> Open Command Prompt in Windows 11 or 10
> Select the Start Menu (the
> Windows icon) in the taskbar, or press the Windows key. Type cmd.
>
> Select Command Prompt from the list. If you're using the latest
> version of Windows 11, Command Prompt will open within Terminal.

[Using cd command in Windows command line](https://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d)

[How to Use the DIR Command in Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/363639/how-to-use-the-dir-command-in-windows/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20DIR,folders%20in%20the%20current%20directory.)

Comment: Did you link what you intended? Your answer is only quote but the quoted content is not present in the linked page.

Comment: Also directions to "show hidden files" seems like a comment at best since its pretty far removed from OPs goal of uninstalling Rust.

Comment: @kmdreko, *the directory is located somewhere that does not exist.*--Do you believe that is true?